# When the Object.h / .cpp compiled

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface

My question is: When is the `Object.h/Object.cpp` (the java Class `"Object"`) compiled?
Is it compiled along with JVM (when JVM is compiled) or it is included to the JVM dynamically (.dll)?

- my question concerns the implementation of JVM
- We assume that it was implemented in C / C ++

The philosophy of JNI is to create native methods and the communication between JVM and these classes are done via DLL files. But for native methods such a Object's native methods i cant understand if these methods communicate with the same way (via DLL files) or different.

Comment: What makes you think that `Object` is written in C/C++ instead of Java?

Comment: You can see the source code for `Object` [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java). It is written in Java.

Comment: Ok the methods are written in C/C++ (keyword 'native') so are implemented in C/C++

Comment: Ok help me to find the correct buzzwords by giving a good answer.

Comment: @luk2302 why did you delete your comment?

Comment: It's hard to give you a good answer when your question is full of misconceptions.  I think you need to research JNI a bit more before you either [edit] this question or ask a new one on this subject.

Comment: I have read it. The philosophy of JNI is to create native methods and the communication between JVM and these classes are done via DLL files.  But for native methods such a Object's native methods i cant understand if these methods communicate with the same way (via DLL files) or different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not specified how JVM links Object's native methods; different JVM implementations may do it differently. As to OpenJDK and HotSpot JVM, there is no magic behind native methods of `java.lang.Object`. They are bound the same way as user-defined natives.

Note: it is not required that the native code for a Java class is loaded from one shared library - it can be scattered round multiple libraries. That's exactly what happen to Object's native methods: some of them are built into JVM, others are implemented in `java.dll`.

When `java.lang.Object` class is initialized, its [`registerNatives`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/65464a307408/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java#l41) method is called. The native implementation of this method is a part of JDK class library. It is compiled from [`Object.c`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/65464a307408/src/java.base/share/native/libjava/Object.c#l50) into `java.dll` at JDK build time.

```
static JNINativeMethod methods[] = {
    {"hashCode",    "()I",                    (void *)&JVM_IHashCode},
    {"wait",        "(J)V",                   (void *)&JVM_MonitorWait},
    {"notify",      "()V",                    (void *)&JVM_MonitorNotify},
    {"notifyAll",   "()V",                    (void *)&JVM_MonitorNotifyAll},
    {"clone",       "()Ljava/lang/Object;",   (void *)&JVM_Clone},
};

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_java_lang_Object_registerNatives(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls)
{
    (*env)->RegisterNatives(env, cls,
                            methods, sizeof(methods)/sizeof(methods[0]));
}
```

This method calls JNI [RegisterNatives](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#RegisterNatives) to bind other native methods of `java.lang.Object`: `hashCode`, `wait`, `notify` etc. The corresponding C++ functions `JVM_IHashCode`, `JVM_MonitorWait` and `JVM_MonitorNotify` are a part of JVM. They are compiled from [`jvm.cpp`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/b756e7a2ec33/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp#l583) to `jvm.dll` at HotSpot build time.

However, one more method, `Object.getClass` is still implemented on [JDK side](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/65464a307408/src/java.base/share/native/libjava/Object.c#l57) using regular JNI interface:

```
JNIEXPORT jclass JNICALL
Java_java_lang_Object_getClass(JNIEnv *env, jobject this)
{
    if (this == NULL) {
        JNU_ThrowNullPointerException(env, NULL);
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for this great answer!  Now, my question is : When registerNative method must be defined? For example here you wrote that for the class "Object" you must define this function, but if i create a native method it needn't define "RegisterNatives" function.

Comment: RegisterNative *

Comment: @LeAdErQ What do you mean? I haven't said that you must define `registerNatives`. This is just one option to bind native methods. You either link methods manually by calling JNI RegisterNatives function or a method is linked automatically on the first call. In the latter case the JVM performs lookup using the specified naming convention: `Java_package_ClassName_methodName`.